# $\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2+2}\,dz$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, complex-numbers, contour-integration, complex-integration

Evaluate $$\int_{\gamma}\frac{1}{z^2+2}dz$$ where $ \gamma(t) = 2i + e^{it} $ and $ 0\leq t \leq 2\pi$

I have already solve a question that was a minus signal instead of a plus signal, and in that question I have used the Cauchy's integral, but for this question, I have some problems to do the $\frac{f(z)}{z-a}$ part of the solution.

Comment: Give that $\gamma$ only contains the pole $z=i\sqrt 2$. Then you can take $f(z)=\frac{1}{z+i\sqrt 2}$. I hope I have understood your question correctly.

Comment: oh, thanks dude, helped a lot.